# google calendar time not showing correct start and end time

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am constructing a link (programmatically) to create a google calendar link. I found that when I pass it a date in the following format

`....&dates=20151005T170000Z/20151007T190000Z&....`

where I'd expect it to show 5:00 PM to 7:00 PM, it instead shows 1:00 PM to 3:00 PM

Here is the full link:

`https://www.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text=The+Annual+%20Event&dates=20151005T170000Z/20151007T190000Z&sprop=website:turnaround.org&location=Fairmont+Scottsdale+Princess+7575+East+Princess+Drive+Scottsdale,+AZ+United+States&details&website=https://example.com&pli=1&sf=true&output=xml#eventpage_6'

My only thought would be that its a timezone issue, but I don't see that anywhere in the url.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing the time zone as Z

```
20151005T170000Z  <-- here at the end of the date/time
```

> The letter Z ("Zulu") indicates Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) or Coordinated Universal Time (see UTC±00:00). They are used in conjunction with military time: for instance, 6:00 a.m. in zone UTC−5 is written "0600R" and spoken "zero six hundred Romeo".

And

https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37064?hl=en

> Google Calendar uses Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) to help avoid issues with daylight savings time.
>
> When events are created, they're converted into UTC, but you'll always see them in your local time.
>
> If an area switches their time zone, events created before we knew about the change might be in the wrong time zone.

So make sure all times are in UTC time or don't put a Z on the time and instead add the &ctz=TIMEZONE to the URL.

Comment: Thanks! That was it! I will make sure to adjust my coding accordingly.