# Google Calendar Event Link shows Coordinated Universal Time on Safari, but it should adjust to the timezone the user is it

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I made a calendar using Fullcalendar that pulls events from a google calendar for a client. When I click on an event, it opens a new window to see the event/add the event to the user's own google calendar. In Safari, it displays the time in UTC instead of the local timezone. Is there any way to force it to display the local timezone from the code? Something I can append to the url? I'm having a hard time googling this.

As far as I can tell, this only happens on Safari. Chrome and Firefox both bring up the local timezone as intended.

My guess is that it's not possible, but since the client's asking, I want to be able to give a definitive answer.

[Intended view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eA3n4.png)

[Actual Safari View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sA3ji.png)

Comment: "it displays the time in UTC instead of the local timezone" Are you referring to how the time appears in your Fullcalendar impelmentation, or on the client's Google Calendar upon clicking the link?

Since Google Calendar's event response returns timezone info (as either an offset or as a timezone string), it should be possible to use that info to display in the user's local time

Comment: In Google Calendar - when you click on an event, it launches a new tab/window in Google Calendar itself, and that's what switches to UTC. The fullcalendar implementation seems to have no issue displaying the right timezone. I've just realized that this seems to only happen if there's no google account logged into, rather than it being a Safari issue. Here's a slightly older version of my code on [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tomatotomato/kfLsgjaw/32/) (though it might not be the most useful example since the example calendar doesn't have times listed).

Comment: Fixed what I was asking here and deleted the other comment, my personal google account somehow got set for a different timezone. It seems a logged in account will override the timezone displayed, but if there's not an account logged in, this solution avoids the timezone being in UTC by default: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32638912/google-calendar-time-not-showing-correct-start-and-end-time